# How to join multiple tables and find pairs

Tags: sql

We are currently studying for a lecture about databases and we are not sure if our solution is the right way to solve this kind of problem.

The following scheme is given:
[image]

Translation of the relevant relations:

- Lecture(**LectureID**[PK], LectureTitle, *ProfInitials*)
- VG(***LectureID***[PK, FK1], ***SubjectTitle***[PK, FK2]
- Subject(***Titel***[PK], Description)

The task is to find pairs of lectures ("Vorlesung") that have a subject ("Gebiet") in common. The resulting table should contain the names of both lectures ("VTitel") and the titel of the shared subject ("Titel").

The soulution we came up with is

```
SELECT "T1"."VTitel", "T2"."VTitel", "T1"."Titel"
FROM (SELECT v1."VTitel", "Titel" FROM "Vorlesung" v1 NATURAL JOIN "VG" g) AS "T1"
JOIN (SELECT v1."VTitel", "Titel" FROM "Vorlesung" v1 NATURAL JOIN "VG" g) AS "T2"
ON "T1"."Titel" = "T2"."Titel" AND "T1"."VTitel" <> "T2"."VTitel";
```

Is this the right way to solve this or is there a much easier way to do this?

Comment: Which database management system are you using? MySQL, SQL-Server, PostgreSQL, Oracle? Something else?

Comment: `NATURAL JOIN` excludes SQL Server. Do you have an ANSI SQL test RDBMS?

Comment: PostgreSQL for testing purposes. But we have to use standard SQL-92.

Comment: I'm curious; why are you tied to a 24 year old standard?

Comment: @HartCO Because they are learning the basics;  I assume the point of the course is to learn the concepts behind databases before learning about how different rdbms offer improvements on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like it will give you the correct answer, however in practice it is usually faster (and often, though not always more readable), to avoid nested sub-queries.  I assume you've had some lectures on relational algebra, so you'll notice that if you translate your query into relational form it turns out to be rather long (I renamed your tables and columns and used [this site](http://dbis-uibk.github.io/relax/calc.htm) to generate it, but you should do it yourself by hand; S is Vorlesung and T is VG, b and d are the two fields in each table):

```
π T1.b, T2.b, T1.d ρ T1 ( π v1.b, v1.d ρ v1 S ⨝ ρ g T) ⨝ T1.d = T2.d and T1.b ≠ T2.b ρ T2 ( π v1.b, v1.d ρ v1 S ⨝ ρ g T)
```

This uses 12 operators. Instead of having selects inside your joins, maybe you want to simply rename all instances of your tables to different names and join them all together!

```
 SELECT V1.VTitel,
        V2.VTitel,
        VG1.Titel
   FROM Vorlesung AS V1 
   JOIN VG AS VG1
     ON VG1.VNummer = V1.VNummer
   JOIN Vorlesung AS V2
     ON V1.VTitel <> V2.VTitel
   JOIN VG AS VG2
     ON VG2.VNummer = V2.VNummer
  WHERE VG2.Titel = VG1.Titel
```

This gives us a more manageable 9 operators:

```
π V1.b, V2.b, V1.d σ VG1.b = VG2.b ρ V1 S ⨝ VG1.d = V1.d ρ VG1 T ⨝ V1.b ≠ V2.b ρ V2 S ⨝ VG2.d = V2.d ρ VG2 T
```

Note I've gotten rid of the natural joins so that we don't have to worry about brackets and such; natural joins are also a terrible thing to use in real life, but make sense in theory.  It's a good exercise to see if you understand what I did if you can rewrite the new query with natural joins, and if you can write it again without a where clause!